# How to convert Symbol font to standard utf8 HTML entity

Tags: php, character-encoding, fonts

Is there any way to convert unicode Symbol font in a html stream to its equivalent utf8 entity  ?

ie. 0xf067 (`&#61543;` as unicode Symbol html entity) to greek small letter gamma (U+03B3 aka `&#947;` in standard utf8)

Comment: Which charset do you use in the HTML stream for the symbol font?

Comment: Easy, you have it already, see my answer. I guess there is more you have not asked for with your question, please elaborate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I managed to do it using the Symbol to unicode map at

http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/CM/AdobeSym.html

then converting from unicode to utf8 with iconv (as unicode <> utf8)

```
function symbol_sanitize_string($string) {
  return preg_replace_callback('/([\x{f020}-\x{f0fe}]{1})/u', 
     'symbol_unicode_to_utf8_entity', $string);
}

function symbol_unicode_to_utf8_entity($wchar) {
  static $_SYMBOL_FONT_MAP = array (
    15696032 => 32,
    15696033 => 33,
    15696034 => 8704,
    15696035 => 35,
    15696036 => 8707,
    15696037 => 37,
    15696038 => 38,
    15696039 => 8715,
    15696040 => 40,
    15696041 => 41,
    15696042 => 8727,
    15696043 => 43,
    15696044 => 44,
    15696045 => 8722,
    15696046 => 46,
    15696047 => 47,
    15696048 => 48,
    15696049 => 49,
    15696050 => 50,
    15696051 => 51,
    15696052 => 52,
    15696053 => 53,
    15696054 => 54,
    15696055 => 55,
    15696056 => 56,
    15696057 => 57,
    15696058 => 58,
    15696059 => 59,
    15696060 => 60,
    15696061 => 61,
    15696062 => 62,
    15696063 => 63,
    15696256 => 8773,
    15696257 => 913,
    15696258 => 914,
    15696259 => 935,
    15696260 => 916,
    15696261 => 917,
    15696262 => 934,
    15696263 => 915,
    15696264 => 919,
    15696265 => 921,
    15696266 => 977,
    15696267 => 922,
    15696268 => 923,
    15696269 => 924,
    15696270 => 925,
    15696271 => 927,
    15696272 => 928,
    15696273 => 920,
    15696274 => 929,
    15696275 => 931,
    15696276 => 932,
    15696277 => 933,
    15696278 => 962,
    15696279 => 937,
    15696280 => 926,
    15696281 => 936,
    15696282 => 918,
    15696283 => 91,
    15696284 => 8756,
    15696285 => 93,
    15696286 => 8869,
    15696287 => 95,
    15696288 => 63717,
    15696289 => 945,
    15696290 => 946,
    15696291 => 967,
    15696292 => 948,
    15696293 => 949,
    15696294 => 966,
    15696295 => 947,
    15696296 => 951,
    15696297 => 953,
    15696298 => 981,
    15696299 => 954,
    15696300 => 955,
    15696301 => 956,
    15696302 => 957,
    15696303 => 959,
    15696304 => 960,
    15696305 => 952,
    15696306 => 961,
    15696307 => 963,
    15696308 => 964,
    15696309 => 965,
    15696310 => 982,
    15696311 => 969,
    15696312 => 958,
    15696313 => 968,
    15696314 => 950,
    15696315 => 123,
    15696316 => 124,
    15696317 => 125,
    15696318 => 8764,
    15696544 => 8364,
    15696545 => 978,
    15696546 => 8242,
    15696547 => 8804,
    15696548 => 8260,
    15696549 => 8734,
    15696550 => 402,
    15696551 => 9827,
    15696552 => 9830,
    15696553 => 9829,
    15696554 => 9824,
    15696555 => 8596,
    15696556 => 8592,
    15696557 => 8593,
    15696558 => 8594,
    15696559 => 8595,
    15696560 => 176,
    15696561 => 177,
    15696562 => 8243,
    15696563 => 8805,
    15696564 => 215,
    15696565 => 8733,
    15696566 => 8706,
    15696567 => 8226,
    15696568 => 247,
    15696569 => 8800,
    15696570 => 8801,
    15696571 => 8776,
    15696572 => 8230,
    15696573 => 63718,
    15696574 => 63719,
    15696575 => 8629,
    15696768 => 8501,
    15696769 => 8465,
    15696770 => 8476,
    15696771 => 8472,
    15696772 => 8855,
    15696773 => 8853,
    15696774 => 8709,
    15696775 => 8745,
    15696776 => 8746,
    15696777 => 8835,
    15696778 => 8839,
    15696779 => 8836,
    15696780 => 8834,
    15696781 => 8838,
    15696782 => 8712,
    15696783 => 8713,
    15696784 => 8736,
    15696785 => 8711,
    15696786 => 63194,
    15696787 => 63193,
    15696788 => 63195,
    15696789 => 8719,
    15696790 => 8730,
    15696791 => 8901,
    15696792 => 172,
    15696793 => 8743,
    15696794 => 8744,
    15696795 => 8660,
    15696796 => 8656,
    15696797 => 8657,
    15696798 => 8658,
    15696799 => 8659,
    15696800 => 9674,
    15696801 => 9001,
    15696802 => 63720,
    15696803 => 63721,
    15696804 => 63722,
    15696805 => 8721,
    15696806 => 63723,
    15696807 => 63724,
    15696808 => 63725,
    15696809 => 63726,
    15696810 => 63727,
    15696811 => 63728,
    15696812 => 63729,
    15696813 => 63730,
    15696814 => 63731,
    15696815 => 63732,
    15696817 => 9002,
    15696818 => 8747,
    15696819 => 8992,
    15696820 => 63733,
    15696821 => 8993,
    15696822 => 63734,
    15696823 => 63735,
    15696824 => 63736,
    15696825 => 63737,
    15696826 => 63738,
    15696827 => 63739,
    15696828 => 63740,
    15696829 => 63741,
    15696830 => 63742,
  );
  $conv = hexdec(bin2hex($wchar[1]));
  $utf8 = $_SYMBOL_FONT_MAP[$conv];    
  return $utf8 ? '&#'. $utf8 .';' : $wchar[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UTF-8` *is* Unicode, you don't need to change anything, you already have it in Unicode.

Comment: yes but i cannot see it because Symbol fonts uses a "private use area". i want to convert it to its "standard" unicode counterpart according to this map http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/CM/AdobeSym.html so i can see it using web safe fonts. maybe the question is deceptive, i hope i've clarified it now.

Comment: Why not just port the map you linked? Have you tried? - And thanks for making this more clear, because I could not understand that from your original question. Keep in mind that others than you are reading the question ;)

Comment: "Why not just port the map you linked?" because that would be very inefficient on large streams, so i'm looking for a more efficient method than scan the whole document char by char inside php

Comment: Maybe [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) is of help here. But in any case, you first need to define which bytes to changes, you'll need to do that in any case. As the link is not PHP, it would be good to have it in some PHP type, like an array. Should be helpful to come closer to a solution (and allows others to get active on the question as well).

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer of [gplotino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21424/gpilotino), I've added some characters not present, extracted from [AdobeSymb](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epaul/R/CM/AdobeSym.html)

```
function symbol_unicode_to_utf8_entity($wchar) {
    static $_SYMBOL_FONT_MAP = array (
        15696032 => "#32",
        15696033 => "#33",
        15696034 => "#8704",
        15696035 => "#35",
        15696036 => "#8707",
        15696037 => "#37",
        15696038 => "#38",
        15696039 => "#8715",
        15696040 => "#40",
        15696041 => "#41",
        15696042 => "#8727",
        15696043 => "#43",
        15696044 => "#44",
        15696045 => "#8722",
        15696046 => "#46",
        15696047 => "#47",
        15696048 => "#48",
        15696049 => "#49",
        15696050 => "#50",
        15696051 => "#51",
        15696052 => "#52",
        15696053 => "#53",
        15696054 => "#54",
        15696055 => "#55",
        15696056 => "#56",
        15696057 => "#57",
        15696058 => "#58",
        15696059 => "#59",
        15696060 => "#60",
        15696061 => "#61",
        15696062 => "#62",
        15696063 => "#63",
        15696256 => "#8773",
        15696257 => "#913",
        15696258 => "#914",
        15696259 => "#935",
        15696260 => "#916",
        15696261 => "#917",
        15696262 => "#934",
        15696263 => "#915",
        15696264 => "#919",
        15696265 => "#921",
        15696266 => "#977",
        15696267 => "#922",
        15696268 => "#923",
        15696269 => "#924",
        15696270 => "#925",
        15696271 => "#927",
        15696272 => "#928",
        15696273 => "#920",
        15696274 => "#929",
        15696275 => "#931",
        15696276 => "#932",
        15696277 => "#933",
        15696278 => "#962",
        15696279 => "#937",
        15696280 => "#926",
        15696281 => "#936",
        15696282 => "#918",
        15696283 => "#91",
        15696284 => "#8756",
        15696285 => "#93",
        15696286 => "#8869",
        15696287 => "#95",
        15696288 => "#63717",
        15696289 => "#945",
        15696290 => "#946",
        15696291 => "#967",
        15696292 => "#948",
        15696293 => "#949",
        15696294 => "#966",
        15696295 => "#947",
        15696296 => "#951",
        15696297 => "#953",
        15696298 => "#981",
        15696299 => "#954",
        15696300 => "#955",
        15696301 => "#956",
        15696302 => "#957",
        15696303 => "#959",
        15696304 => "#960",
        15696305 => "#952",
        15696306 => "#961",
        15696307 => "#963",
        15696308 => "#964",
        15696309 => "#965",
        15696310 => "#982",
        15696311 => "#969",
        15696312 => "#958",
        15696313 => "#968",
        15696314 => "#950",
        15696315 => "#123",
        15696316 => "#124",
        15696317 => "#125",
        15696318 => "#8764",
        15696544 => "#8364",
        15696545 => "#978",
        15696546 => "#8242",
        15696547 => "#8804",
        15696548 => "#8260",
        15696549 => "#8734",
        15696550 => "#402",
        15696551 => "#9827",
        15696552 => "#9830",
        15696553 => "#9829",
        15696554 => "#9824",
        15696555 => "#8596",
        15696556 => "#8592",
        15696557 => "#8593",
        15696558 => "#8594",
        15696559 => "#8595",
        15696560 => "#176",
        15696561 => "#177",
        15696562 => "#8243",
        15696563 => "#8805",
        15696564 => "#215",
        15696565 => "#8733",
        15696566 => "#8706",
        15696567 => "#8226",
        15696568 => "#247",
        15696569 => "#8800",
        15696570 => "#8801",
        15696571 => "#8776",
        15696572 => "#8230",
        15696573 => "#63718",
        15696574 => "#63719",
        15696575 => "#8629",
        15696768 => "#8501",
        15696769 => "#8465",
        15696770 => "#8476",
        15696771 => "#8472",
        15696772 => "#8855",
        15696773 => "#8853",
        15696774 => "#8709",
        15696775 => "#8745",
        15696776 => "#8746",
        15696777 => "#8835",
        15696778 => "#8839",
        15696779 => "#8836",
        15696780 => "#8834",
        15696781 => "#8838",
        15696782 => "#8712",
        15696783 => "#8713",
        15696784 => "#8736",
        15696785 => "#8711",
        15696786 => "#63194",
        15696787 => "#63193",
        15696788 => "#63195",
        15696789 => "#8719",
        15696790 => "#8730",
        15696791 => "#8901",
        15696792 => "#172",
        15696793 => "#8743",
        15696794 => "#8744",
        15696795 => "#8660",
        15696796 => "#8656",
        15696797 => "#8657",
        15696798 => "#8658",
        15696799 => "#8659",
        15696800 => "#9674",
        15696801 => "#9001",
        15696802 => "#63720",
        15696803 => "#63721",
        15696804 => "#63722",
        15696805 => "#8721",
        15696806 => "#63723",
        15696807 => "#63724",
        15696808 => "#63725",
        15696809 => "#63726",
        15696810 => "#63727",
        15696811 => "#63728",
        15696812 => "#63729",
        15696813 => "#63730",
        15696814 => "#63731",
        15696815 => "#63732",
        15696817 => "#9002",
        15696818 => "#8747",
        15696819 => "#8992",
        15696820 => "#63733",
        15696821 => "#8993",
        15696822 => "#63734",
        15696823 => "#63735",
        15696824 => "#63736",
        15696825 => "#63737",
        15696826 => "#63738",
        15696827 => "#63739",
        15696828 => "#63740",
        15696829 => "#63741",
        15696830 => "#63742",
        36 => "exist",
        38 => "amp",
        39 => "ni",
        42 => "lowast",
        45 => "minus",
        60 => "lt",
        62 => "gt",
        64 => "cong",
        65 => "Alpha",
        66 => "Beta",
        67 => "Chi",
        68 => "Delta",
        69 => "Epsilon",
        70 => "Phi",
        71 => "Gamma",
        72 => "Eta",
        73 => "Iota",
        74 => "thetasym",
        75 => "Kappa",
        76 => "Lambda",
        77 => "Mu",
        78 => "Nu",
        79 => "Omicron",
        80 => "Pi",
        81 => "Theta",
        82 => "Rho",
        83 => "Sigma",
        84 => "Tau",
        85 => "Upsilon",
        86 => "sigmaf",
        87 => "Omega",
        88 => "Xi",
        89 => "Psi",
        90 => "Zeta",
        92 => "there4",
        94 => "perp",
        97 => "alpha",
        98 => "beta",
        99 => "chi",
        100 => "delta",
        101 => "epsilon",
        102 => "phi",
        103 => "gamma",
        104 => "eta",
        105 => "iota",
        106 => "&#x3d5;",
        107 => "kappa",
        108 => "lambda",
        109 => "mu",
        110 => "nu",
        111 => "omicron",
        112 => "pi",
        113 => "theta",
        114 => "rho",
        115 => "sigma",
        116 => "tau",
        117 => "upsilon",
        118 => "piv",
        119 => "omega",
        120 => "xi",
        121 => "psi",
        122 => "zeta",
        126 => "sim",
        160 => "euro",
        161 => "upsih",
        162 => "prime",
        163 => "le",
        164 => "frasl",
        165 => "infin",
        166 => "fnof",
        167 => "clubs",
        168 => "diams",
        169 => "hearts",
        170 => "spades",
        171 => "harr",
        172 => "larr",
        173 => "uarr",
        174 => "rarr",
        175 => "darr",
        176 => "deg",
        177 => "plusmn",
        178 => "Prime",
        179 => "ge",
        180 => "times",
        181 => "prop",
        182 => "part",
        183 => "bull",
        184 => "divide",
        185 => "ne",
        186 => "equiv",
        187 => "asymp",
        188 => "hellip",
        191 => "crarr",
        192 => "alefsym",
        193 => "image",
        194 => "real",
        195 => "weierp",
        196 => "otimes",
        197 => "oplus",
        198 => "empty",
        199 => "cap",
        200 => "cup",
        201 => "sup",
        202 => "supe",
        203 => "nsub",
        204 => "sub",
        205 => "sube",
        206 => "isin",
        207 => "notin",
        208 => "ang",
        209 => "nabla",
        210 => "reg",
        211 => "copy",
        212 => "trade",
        213 => "prod",
        214 => "radic",
        215 => "sdot",
        216 => "not",
        217 => "and",
        218 => "or",
        219 => "hArr",
        220 => "lArr",
        221 => "uArr",
        222 => "rArr",
        223 => "dArr",
        224 => "loz",
        225 => "lang",
        229 => "sum",
        241 => "rang",
        242 => "int",
    );
    $conv = hexdec(bin2hex($wchar));
    $utf8 = $_SYMBOL_FONT_MAP[$conv];    
    return $utf8 ? '&'. $utf8 .';' : $wchar;
}
// Usage.
// Assume letter from format like:
// <span style="font-family:Symbol;">m</span>
// Intermediate processing: "m" => "&mu;"
$intermediate = symbol_unicode_to_utf8_entity('m');
// Output UTF character "μ"
echo html_entity_decode($intermediate, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');
```

**EDIT**: Previous script was not converting some characters, as ). So I've written a new script that parses directly decimal value of non unicode symbol characters to unicode ( table extracted from [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/symbol/nonunicode.htm):

```
function symbol_sanitize_string($string) {

//important if you're use DOM to load html
$string = preg_replace( '/charset=iso-8859-1/', 'charset=utf-8', $string );
    
//replace font symbols
$string =  preg_replace_callback('/&#(61\d+?);/i', 'symbol_alone2utf8', $string);
 
return $string;
 
}

function symbol_alone2utf8( $match ){
 return symbol2utf8( $match[1] );
}

function symbol2utf8( $decimal ) {

$_Symbol = array(
    61472 => '020',
    61473 => '021',
    61474 => '022',
    61475 => '023',
    61476 => '024',
    61477 => '025',
    61478 => '026',
    61479 => '027',
    61480 => '028',
    61481 => '029',
    61482 => '02A',
    61483 => '02B',
    61484 => '02C',
    61485 => '02D',
    61486 => '02E',
    61487 => '02F',
    61488 => '030',
    61489 => '031',
    61490 => '032',
    61491 => '033',
    61492 => '034',
    61493 => '035',
    61494 => '036',
    61495 => '037',
    61496 => '038',
    61497 => '039',
    61498 => '03A',
    61499 => '03B',
    61500 => '03C',
    61501 => '03D',
    61502 => '03E',
    61503 => '03F',
    61504 => '040',
    61505 => '041',
    61506 => '042',
    61507 => '043',
    61508 => '044',
    61509 => '045',
    61510 => '046',
    61511 => '047',
    61512 => '048',
    61513 => '049',
    61514 => '04A',
    61515 => '04B',
    61516 => '04C',
    61517 => '04D',
    61518 => '04E',
    61519 => '04F',
    61520 => '050',
    61521 => '051',
    61522 => '052',
    61523 => '053',
    61524 => '054',
    61525 => '055',
    61526 => '056',
    61527 => '057',
    61528 => '058',
    61529 => '059',
    61530 => '05A',
    61531 => '05B',
    61532 => '05C',
    61533 => '05D',
    61534 => '05E',
    61535 => '05F',
    61536 => '060',
    61537 => '061',
    61538 => '062',
    61539 => '063',
    61540 => '064',
    61541 => '065',
    61542 => '066',
    61543 => '067',
    61544 => '068',
    61545 => '069',
    61546 => '06A',
    61547 => '06B',
    61548 => '06C',
    61549 => '06D',
    61550 => '06E',
    61551 => '06F',
    61552 => '070',
    61553 => '071',
    61554 => '072',
    61555 => '073',
    61556 => '074',
    61557 => '075',
    61558 => '076',
    61559 => '077',
    61560 => '078',
    61561 => '079',
    61562 => '07A',
    61563 => '07B',
    61564 => '07C',
    61565 => '07D',
    61566 => '07E',
    61601 => '0A1',
    61602 => '0A2',
    61603 => '0A3',
    61604 => '0A4',
    61605 => '0A5',
    61606 => '0A6',
    61607 => '0A7',
    61608 => '0A8',
    61609 => '0A9',
    61610 => '0AA',
    61611 => '0AB',
    61612 => '0AC',
    61613 => '0AD',
    61614 => '0AE',
    61615 => '0AF',
    61616 => '0B0',
    61617 => '0B1',
    61618 => '0B2',
    61619 => '0B3',
    61620 => '0B4',
    61621 => '0B5',
    61622 => '0B6',
    61623 => '0B7',
    61624 => '0B8',
    61625 => '0B9',
    61626 => '0BA',
    61627 => '0BB',
    61628 => '0BC',
    61629 => '0BD',
    61630 => '0BE',
    61631 => '0BF',
    61632 => '0C0',
    61633 => '0C1',
    61634 => '0C2',
    61635 => '0C3',
    61636 => '0C4',
    61637 => '0C5',
    61638 => '0C6',
    61639 => '0C7',
    61640 => '0C8',
    61641 => '0C9',
    61642 => '0CA',
    61643 => '0CB',
    61644 => '0CC',
    61645 => '0CD',
    61646 => '0CE',
    61647 => '0CF',
    61648 => '0D0',
    61649 => '0D1',
    61650 => '0D2',
    61651 => '0D3',
    61652 => '0D4',
    61653 => '0D5',
    61654 => '0D6',
    61655 => '0D7',
    61656 => '0D8',
    61657 => '0D9',
    61658 => '0DA',
    61659 => '0DB',
    61660 => '0DC',
    61661 => '0DD',
    61662 => '0DE',
    61663 => '0DF',
    61664 => '0E0',
    61665 => '0E1',
    61666 => '0E2',
    61667 => '0E3',
    61668 => '0E4',
    61669 => '0E5',
    61670 => '0E6',
    61671 => '0E7',
    61672 => '0E8',
    61673 => '0E9',
    61674 => '0EA',
    61675 => '0EB',
    61676 => '0EC',
    61677 => '0ED',
    61678 => '0EE',
    61679 => '0EF',
    61681 => '0F1',
    61682 => '0F2',
    61683 => '0F3',
    61684 => '0F4',
    61685 => '0F5',
    61686 => '0F6',
    61687 => '0F7',
    61688 => '0F8',
    61689 => '0F9',
    61690 => '0FA',
    61691 => '0FB',
    61692 => '0FC',
    61693 => '0FD',
    61694 => '0FE'
    
  );

  $key = $decimal;
  if( array_key_exists( $key, $_Symbol ) ){
    
    if( $key <= 61487 )
        $c = '0';
    else
        $c = 'f';
    
      $char = json_decode( '"\u' . $c . $_Symbol[ $key ] . '"');
      
      return $char;
  }else{
      echo "char not found <br>\n";
      return "&#$decimal;";
  }
}
```

This script have been tested on the conversion of large doc files to html, with high frequency of mathematical symbols.

To test it from an html file, use this code:

```
$string = file_get_contents( 'testfile.html' );

$string = symbol_sanitize_string( $string );
 
echo $string;
//ensure that string is UTF-8 encoded
echo mb_detect_encoding($string) . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The Adobe Symbol encoding to unicode mappings can be found here:
ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/ADOBE/symbol.txt

I made a python3 class that lets you convert at the char level. Check it out on github:
https://github.com/Oufattole/Adobe-Symbol-Encodings-to-Unicode

It seems that you can just take the last two hex digits of an Adobe encoded symbol and the symbol to unicode mapping (from the first link) can map that to the right unicode char.